# Open specific fragment on push notification tap

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have multiple cloud functions that send push notifications, each one is triggered according to changes in the firebase realtime database.

I also have an activity with different fragments.

What i want is to open a specific fragment on notification tap, based on the function that generated the push notification.

Any ideas on how this could be done ? Do i put some kind of flag in the notification payload ?

Comment: On Tap of notification you have to open that activity which contains fragment and pass flag to `onNewIntent()` method in activity and call your particular fragment which you want.

Comment: Yes you have to manage things in payload, like send a type in payload, example: 1 for login 2 . for sign up

Comment: @Piyush `onNewIntent()` wasn't getting called for some reason, so i added my code to `onResume()` instead

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh Thankyou, i added `click_action` to my data payload